# generate dropdown with popup box and then retrive it's value?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have a table **hotels** with **hotel_id** and **hotel_name**

and

I have a link

```
<a href = "#" id="hotel">Post</a>
```

When I click on the above link I want to generate a popup box with drop down (where option value=hotel_id and Text to shown is hotel_name) and when user select hotel from drop down how I get the option value in php.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I am able to generate alert box with the hotel_names but not able how to get the selected value.

Comment: You should show more your code in answer box.

Answer (score 0):

in your a.html:

```
<a href="#" id="hotel" onclick="return openHotelPopup(hotelnames.php);">Post</a>
```

in Javascript:

```
function openHotelPopup(url)
{
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
}
```

in hotelnames.php

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","test","abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_hotels");

echo '<form name="myform" method="post"><select name="hotels" onchange="myform.submit();">';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['hotel_id'].'>'.$row['hotel_name'].'</option>';
  }
echo "</select></form>";

mysql_close($con);
```

Now your popup drop down menu will appear like below:

```
   <form name="myform" method="post">
   <select name="hotels" onchange="myform.submit();">
   <option value="1">Vol</option>
   <option value="2">Sa</option>
   <option value="3">Op</option>
   <option value="4">Au</option>
   </select>
   </form>
```

When you select any one of the option from this drop down menu you retrieve the value in PHP using the following PHP code.

```
<?php
print_r($_REQUEST['hotels'])
?>
```

Output will be:

```
Array ( [hotels] => 1 ); (if you would have selected Vol in drop down menu)
```

Comment: Please read my question again. first I want to generate drop down with javascript or jquery(when I click on <a>tag) with the hotel_names

Comment: of course you must add form tag in hotelnames.php and give name for the form as myform. (changes done in hotelnames.php) Note: You must know the basic knowledge of Javascript and HTML